# Making a Table with CSS

Tags: css

What's the best way to use divs to create a table effect like this html table:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            Name: 
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            Jennifer
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            Age: 
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            19
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

No matter how I do it, my problem is always the text alignment. All this needs to be in another div that has a specific width and floats right and this table would be inside "centered". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question: What are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to do a CSS layout to replace a table layout, or are you trying to display tabular data?

Comment: Stargazer712 I guess a little of both, all the data comes from my SQL DB (Name, Age etc.)

Comment: the litmus test for me is Excel. If you wouldn't do it in Excel, don't do it using a table. If you *would* do it in Excel, then use a table! That's what its there for :). Table tags are only bad when used for *layouts*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the table.

If it ain't broke don't fix it. Use elements that make sense for the data that you're trying to display. In this case, the table makes perfect sense.

Comment: I agree.  The table is made for displaying tabular data.  I'd steered clear of tables for a while because I was told they shouldn't be used in web pages.  However, it's not that they **shouldn't** be used, they shouldn't be used for website **layout**.  I'm getting used to them again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample a definition list is another semantic option:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Jennifer</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd>19</dd>
</dl>
```

You could then use `display: table-cell` to give the data table like look & behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I would do HTML like this:

```
<div class='lefty'>Name:</div><div class='righty'>Jenifer</div>
<div class='lefty'>Age:</div><div class='righty'>19</div>
```

and CSS like this:

```
div{
    width:50%;
    float: left
}
.lefty{
    text-align: right;
}
.righty{
    text-align:left;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SbXdG/

Comment: I don't understand this part below, I certainly can't have a div definition defining all my divs at 50% and floating left.              div
{
    width:50%;
    float: left;
}

Comment: You can make the div width whatever value you like - to match the table, then the width of `.lefty` and `.righty` should add up to 100%. Floating them left stops them from stacking on top of each other. Naturally, divs are block level elements. You need it to display inline somehow otherwise the divs will stack vertically.